# Angular improving large component loading time

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a pretty large component which loads over 1000 data elements.  These data elements are populated via a service, which is only called once.  In the original implementation, the service was called each time the component was initialized, which is where I thought the problem was.  So, I created a shared service that is only called once in a grandparent component.

The component hierarchical structure is as follows:

- AddComponent (grandparent)

  - Type1AddComponent

    - BlockComponent (component with 1000+ data elements)
  - Type2AddComponent

    - BlockComponent
  - Type3AddComponent

    - BlockComponent

As can be seen, the `BlockComponent` is being used in all three `TypeComponents`.  The `BlockComponent` data that is shown in the three different `TypeComponents` is the same (albeit a **title** @Input).  The very first initialization of a `TypeComponent` loads fine, but when switching between them, load times exceed 3 seconds, which I think is unreasonable.  Is there a way to speed up the load times?

I know there is a lot of code being shared below.  I would create a Plunker if I knew how to do so for a **webpack** project.

**shared-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataResolver } from '../../blocking/data/data.resolver';
import { Data } from 'si-data-model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Logger } from 'ngx-data-utils';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  data: Data[] = []; // shared data
  dataObs$: Observable<Data[]>;
  logger: Logger;
  completed = false; // used to signal whether the service has completed to components

  constructor(private resolver: DataResolver,
              logger: Logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.debug('Data Service initialized.');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.logger.debug('Data Service destroyed.');
  }

  load() {
    return this.resolver.resolve(); // retrieves the data elements from a web service
  }

  initData() {
    this.dataObs$ = this.load();
    this.dataObs$.subscribe((res: Data[]) => {
      this.data = res;
      this.completed = true;
    });
  }

}
```

**add.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.scss']
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  radioUrl: string;

  constructor(private service: DataService) {
    console.log('Add component built');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.initData();
    console.log('Add component initialized');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('Add component destroyed');
  }

}
```

**type1.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'type1',
  templateUrl: './type1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./type1.component.scss']
})
export class Type1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  title = 'Add Block Stuff';

  constructor() {
    console.log('Type1 component built');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Type1 component initialized');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('Type1 component destroyed');
  }

  onType1Change($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

**block.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Logger } from 'ngx-data-utils';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Data } from 'si-data-model';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'block',
  templateUrl: './block.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./block.component.scss']
})

export class BlockComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  dataLoaded = false;
  labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4',
    'Label5'];
  selected: any[] = [];
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
  data3: string;
  data4: string;
  data5: string;
  data6: string;
  datas: Data[] = [];
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() data: Data[];

  // private criteriaCodes = [6, 2, 3, 11, 29, 25];

  constructor(private logger: Logger,
              private dataService: DataService) {
                // TODO
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display();
    this.logger.debug('BlockComponent initialized.');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.logger.debug('BlockComponent destroyed.');
  }

  initData () {
    this.dataService.data.forEach((dt: Data) => {
      this.datas.push(dt);
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  display() {
    if (this.dataService.completed) 
      this.initData();
  }

  propagateChange() {
    this.change.emit(this.selected); // doesn't do anything yet
  }

}
```

**block.component.html**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="dataLoaded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL1' | translate}}</label>
      <select class="custom-select form-control" [(ngModel)]="data1" (change)="propagateChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let c of data[0].value">{{c.code}} - {{c.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL2' | translate}}</label>
      <select class="custom-select form-control" [(ngModel)]="data2" (change)="propagateChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let mt of data[1].value">{{mt.code}} - {{mt.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL3' | translate}}</label>
      <select class="custom-select form-control" [(ngModel)]="data3" (change)="propagateChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let pem of data[2].value">{{pem.code}} - {{pem.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL4' | translate}}</label>
      <select class="custom-select form-control" [(ngModel)]="data4" (change)="propagateChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let tt of data[3].value">{{tt.code}} - {{tt.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL5' | translate}}</label>
      <select class="custom-select form-control" [(ngModel)]="data5" (change)="propagateChange()">
        <option *ngFor="let cl of data[4].value">{{cl.code}} - {{cl.description}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>{{'DATA.BLOCK.LABEL6' | translate}}</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding using a plunker, you can just add code to the generated Angular snippet (in Plunker, just select `New | Angular`). And add your code. Sure it's Systemjs, but it should still demo your issue. (Unless you think it is a Webpack issue?)

Comment: I don't think it's a webpack issue.  It will take me a little bit of time to rip some stuff out (like translations) and get the Plunkr working, but that's better than posting a thousand lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `add.component.ts` is regetting the data every time it is initialized again?

Could you just do this:

```
  initData() {
    if (!this.data) {
      this.dataObs$ = this.load();
      this.dataObs$.subscribe((res: Data[]) => {
        this.data = res;
        this.completed = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Then it won't re-load the data once it's retrieved it.

Regarding the child components, it appears that at least one of them is looping through *EVERY* element and creating its own copy of the data array?

```
  initData () {
    this.dataService.data.forEach((dt: Data) => {
      this.datas.push(dt);
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    });
```

Instead, try using a getter:

```
export class BlockComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  get datas(): Data[] {
      return this.dataService.data;
  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying.  It's hard to test without a plunker... It is true that the add component gets the data every time it is initialized, but it's children aren't. Eventually I will address this.  Right now, the problem lies with the children load times.  It takes 3+ seconds to switch between the children even though the web service is only called once.  I tried your code and got the same result I was getting before.

Comment: Also, just wondering if you really need to download all 10,000 elements right away. A user can't really process that much data visually. You may want to also consider breaking that out and only downloading hunks of it as a time. Maybe page it, or allow the user to select filter criteria before downloading.

Comment: Regarding the updated answer, there are 6 elements that are being copied.  Each of these elements is an array with a lot of other elements.  I am guessing the copy is what's causing the slow down  Regarding your comment, you are probably right that  I don't need to load all the data elements right away since the user will only be in one dropdown at any given time.

Comment: I have an idea of what to do now... just use the shared variable "data" from the service and loop through it in an *ngFor to display what I need to instead of copying.

Comment: Or if you want to wrap it, just use a getter. That way your template is not directly referencing your service.

Comment: Eh still having the load time issues without the copy, but I think that's the right path to go down.  Thank you for your help.  I'll come back here when I have found a good solution.

Comment: And a plunker would help us look into it further ... if you have time.